# Echo out from a Laravel 8 Eloquent collection

Tags: collections, eloquent, relationship, laravel-8

I have this collection

[image: I have this collection:]

[image]

How can I echo the relations in Blade? I try this code:

```
@forelse($articles as $article)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $article->title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $article->excerpt }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $article->body }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $article->colors->name }}</td>
```

...
But I get: "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\articles\index.blade.php)"

Comment: Please combine the 2 non-answers into your question itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Collection` (albeit of only a single `Color`), so you'll need either a nested `@foreach()`, or a `pluck()`:

```php
@forelse($articles as $article)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $article->title }}</td>
    ...
    @foreach($article->colors as $color)
      // Do something with `$color->name`
    @endforeach
  </tr>
@empty
  ...
@endforelse

// OR

@forelse($articles as $article)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $article->title }}</td>
    ...
    <td>{{ $article->colors->pluck('name')->implode(', ') }}</td> // Purple
  </tr>
@empty
  ...
@endforelse
```

Basically, you can't echo a single property (like `->name`) from a Collection. The code won't know which one you're trying to return. This applies even if the relationship returns a single record. If you only want a single color, then you'd need to modify your relationship to as `hasOne()`, then you'd be able to do something like:

```
$article->color->name ?? 'None'
```